# How to test ForwardRwf components with jest/enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have such a component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class TopicsList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      topics: [...],
    };
    this.references = [];
  }

getOrCreateRef(id) {
  if (!this.references.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    this.references[id] = React.createRef();
  }
  return this.references[id];
}

  render() {
    const {
     topics
    } = this.state;

  
    return (       
        <div>
          <ul>
            {topics.map((topic) => (
                <TopicItem
                  key={topic.id}
                  topic={topic}
                  ref={this.getOrCreateRef(topic.id)}
                />
              )
            )}
          </ul>
        </div>
        
    )
  }
}
    const TopicItem = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    
      return (
        <li
        >
          <p>{props.name}</p>
          <i
            className="fal fa-plus"
          />
        </li>
      );
    });
```

I wrote test to test how much li items will be rendered:

```
test('should render 3 li items', () => {
      console.log(wrapper.debug())
      expect(wrapper.find('TopicItem').length).toBe(3);
    });
```

but my test failed because in jest they recognized like:

```
<ul>
  <ForwardRef topic={{...}} />
  <ForwardRef  topic={{...}} />
  <ForwardRef  topic={{...}} />
</ul>
```

How can I test components that are returned with `React.forwardRef`?
I cannot find appropriate solutions on the internet or here.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit late, but assigning the `displayName` property to the wrapped component can help. Enzyme respects `displayName` and uses it when creating snapshots (rendering it instead of `ForwardRef` in this case), and `find` also works with display names.